Restrict access to vault secrets according to token group claims
I would like to let users log in to Vault and manage secrets that sit at paths matching the groups they belong to.
For example if an user belongs to groups CARPORT_USERS and PO_BUSINESS_FRANCE they should be able to access secrets at, respectively, partners/CARPORT_USERS/* and partners/PO_BUSINESS_FRANCE/*
My setup has Vault using Keycloak as an OIDC provider.
This is an example token I generated using Vault's "evaluate" feature.
{
  "exp": 1712671737,
  "iat": 1712671677,
  "auth_time": 0,
  "jti": "<an uuid>",
  "iss": "https://<keycloak-instance>/auth/realms/master",
  "aud": "vault_client_test",
  "sub": "b3f00812-d4d8-4831-8ee1-5cb900362571",
  "typ": "ID",
  "azp": "vault_client_test",
  "session_state": "<another uuid>",
  "acr": "1",
  "sid": "<an uuid too>",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "Michel Rodrigues",
  "groups": [
    "PO_BUSINESS_FRANCE",
    "CARPORT_USERS",
    "TRANSIT_USERS"
  ],
  "preferred_username": "d47210",
  "given_name": "Michel",
  "family_name": "Rodrigues",
  "email": "michel.rodrigues@company.com"

}

This is vault's oidc config
vault read auth/oidc/config
Key                       Value
---                       -----
bound_issuer              https://<keycloak-instance>/auth/realms/master
default_role              partner-role
jwks_ca_pem               n/a
jwks_url                  n/a
jwt_supported_algs        []
jwt_validation_pubkeys    []
namespace_in_state        true
oidc_client_id            vault_client_test
oidc_discovery_ca_pem     n/a
oidc_discovery_url        https://<keycloak-instance>/auth/realms/master
oidc_response_mode        n/a
oidc_response_types       []
provider_config           map[]

This is the partner-role role:
vault read auth/oidc/role/partner-role
Key                        Value
---                        -----
allowed_redirect_uris      [http://localhost:8200/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback http://localhost:8250/oidc/callback]
bound_audiences            [vault_client_test]
bound_claims               <nil>
bound_claims_type          string
bound_subject              n/a
claim_mappings             map[{groups:metadata_groups}]
clock_skew_leeway          0
expiration_leeway          0
groups_claim               groups
max_age                    0
not_before_leeway          0
oidc_scopes                <nil>
role_type                  oidc
token_bound_cidrs          []
token_explicit_max_ttl     0s
token_max_ttl              0s
token_no_default_policy    false
token_num_uses             0
token_period               0s
token_policies             [ecosyste_crud_policy]
token_ttl                  0s
token_type                 default
user_claim                 sub
user_claim_json_pointer    false
verbose_oidc_logging       false

Policy ecosyste_crud_policy
path "partners/data/*" {
  capabilities = ["list","read"]
}
 
path "partners/metadata/*" {
  capabilities = ["list","read"]
}

That setup lets user log in to Vault's web console, and see a test secret at partners/something.
Reusing my example token, if this claim is provided by keycloak at login time:
 {"groups": [
    "PO_BUSINESS_FRANCE",
    "CARPORT_USERS",
    "TRANSIT_USERS"
  ]}

and both secrets partners/PO_BUSINESS_FRANCE/api-key-1 and partners/TRANSIT_USERS/bank-iban-0 exists
What would I need to change for the logged user to access partners/PO_BUSINESS_FRANCE/api-key-1 and partners/TRANSIT_USERS/bank-iban-0only ?
What should be done for the user to see their human name when clicking on Vault's user icon in the top left part of the web console, instead of a string with the format oidc-{{uuid}} ?
